# How to add a set of parameters to all actions before executing the reducer?

Tags: redux

I'm looking for a way to add some parameters to every action when entering a (root) reducer.

Quick example, let's presume I have a `userState` that, among other things holds the currently signed in user, maybe in some child state even.

```
  rootState
     |
     +-------------------------------------+
     |                                     |
 userState                            +----+-----+
     |                                |          |
 +---+-----------+                   ...     salesState
 |               |
...    currentlySignedInUserState
```

In order to execute an action in another reducer (say, `salesReducer`) I need to have the currently signed in user, which is not readily available (in a sibling state or worse) so I have to intercept that action in the root state, read `currentlySignedInUserState` from `userState`, add the user to the action payload and reissue the action with the changed payload.

```
case SALES_ACTIONS.ADD_SALE:
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
        let payload = Object.assign({}, action.payload, {
            userName: state.user.signedIn.name
        });
        sales: salesReducer(state.sales, {
            type: SALES_ACTION.ADD_SALE,
            payload
        });
});
```

This gets messy in a jiffy and prevents me from using `combineReducers` because I have to forward each and every single action in a root reducer of my own making.

So I came up with the idea of just adding the user to every action when it enters the root reducer and then just `combineReducers` all the way.

Is that an accepted approach and if so, is there a way to extend `combineReducers` so that it takes additional payload parameters (I was thinking [redux-reuse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-reuse), but I'm unsure if that will do what I have in mind).

If not, what are my alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple [middleware](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html) that gets the `userName` from the state, and adds it as `meta` data to all actions unless not `signedIn`. You can add other conditions, such as specific actions that should be skipped.
I prefer adding additional data as `meta`, and not payload.
I've included two ways to augment the action.

The (untested) code:

```
const middleware = ({ getState }) => next => action => {
  const state = getState();

  if(!state.user.signedIn) { // if not signed in skip
        return next(action);
  }

  const userName = state.user.signedIn.name;

  /** add userName using assign **/
  const meta = Object.assign({}, action.meta, { userName });
  const newAction = Object.assign({}, action, { meta });
  /**********************/

  /** or add userName using object spread **/
  const newAction = { 
    ...action, 
    meta: { ...action.meta, username } 
  };
  /**********************/

  next(newAction);
};
```